# Is it possible to use pronouns before prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, pronouns, parts-of-speech

I have a parts of speech worksheet where it asks to use a pronoun before a preposition in a sentence and I don’t think it is possible.

Here is the problem:
Pronoun / Preposition / Pronoun-Adjective / Noun / Verb / Adjective.

Comment: Not possible? Ye of little faith.

Comment: What's a pronoun-adjective?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian That’s what I asked myself earlier, but I eventually found out what they were. Some examples are these, those, that, each, either, etc...

Comment: None of these pigs became thin. Everyone from that train escaped uninjured.

Answer (score 1):

A pronoun followed by a preposition is actually extremely common: it just usually involves words that aren’t *personal* pronouns such as:

- *Everyone* on earth
- *None* of you
- *Lots* of money
- *Anyone* with time

There are some cases where a personal pronoun is followed by a preposition but not as many because it’s a bit awkward grammatically sometimes to do this and also there’s usually not a reason to. You might do it to further specify who you mean as in “you with the purple shirt” for example but you wouldn’t say the same thing with “I/me” because those pronouns can only refer to one person.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found two definitions for “pronoun adjective”, so I’ll give both a try:

- He in his youth was foolish.
- He on some days is foolish.

However, while a part of my brain tells me these should both be valid, a deeper part recoils at reading them.

If we can use commas, these feel a little better:

- He, in his youth, was foolish.
- He, on some days, is foolish.

But I’d still rather move the PP somewhere else in the sentence. *Anywhere* else.

Answer (score 0):

A clarification in a comment under the question says that so-called pronoun-adjectives include *these*, *those*, *that*, *each*, and *either*. That's an odd mix of what would normally be called demonstrative and indefinite pronouns. (Why not *his* or *her* coming immediately before a noun?) However, for the sake of this question, I will limit myself to only those listed.

I will also limit myself to a personal pronoun in the case of the first word, in order to clearly differentiate it from the other pronoun.

---

Here are some words that match the stated criteria:

- she (pronoun)
- of (preposition)
- this (pronoun-adjective)
- story (noun)
- clicked (verb)
- ruby (adjective)

Assembling those words into a sentence produces the following:

- She of this story clicked ruby slippers together in order to return home.

---

The sentence is grammatical; however, it is not entirely idiomatic. The *she of* construction is old fashioned, in that it was used more often in the past than it is now.

Also, *of this story* would only sound appropriate if the sentence appeared after one or more others that defined the referent.

For instance, the following makes the sentence much more natural in context:

- *The Wizard of Oz* was a book written by L. Frank Baum. As with many protagonists in similar stories, it tells a tale of being transported to a different world and trying to find some way of getting back. She of this story clicked ruby slippers together in order to return home.

The *she of* construction still sound unusual, and would most likely be changed to *the protagonist of* by most people. Despite that, it's not actually ungrammatical.

*She of this story* refers back to *many protagonists in similar stories*.